# Is it possible use an Angular library outside component class?

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, node-modules, ngxs

Long short story. I'm playing around with an Electron and Angular app, I'm using ngxs as my store management.

I've a .ts file with a set of menus that will apply on application init, so what I'm attempting to do is set a function on menu's click event and dispatch an action.

```
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
const store = Store;

const menus = [
    {
      label: 'Electron App',
      role: 'appMenu',
      submenu: [
        { label: 'About Electron App', role: 'about' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        {
          label: 'Preferences...',
          accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+P',

          // Dispatch Action on click
          click: () => store.dispatch()

        },
        { label: 'Check For Updates...' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { label: 'Quit Electron App', role: 'quit' }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'File',
      role: 'fileMenu',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Add File...'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Help',
      role: 'help',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Toggle Developer Tools',
          role: 'toggleDevTools'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

But looks like I'm no getting the correct reference to my Store class.
[image]

This is the first time I try to achieve something like this, so I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: have you tried to import store in your component ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the store on other components of the app but I'm just wondering if it's possible to use the store like the code above